# Form submit doesn't work after calling return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code.

```js
function stop() {
  $("#login_form").submit(function(e) {
    return false;
  });
}

function login() {
  var username = $("input[name=username]").val();
  var password = $("input[name=password]").val();

  if (username.length < 1) {
    alert("Please enter your username or email address.");
    stop();
  } else if (username.length > 0 && username.length < 3) {
    alert("Your username or email is incorrect.");
    stop();
  } else if (password.length < 1) {
    alert("Please enter your password.");
    stop();
  } else if (password.length > 0 && password.length < 6) {
    alert("Your password is incorrect.");
    stop();
  } else if (username.length > 2 && password.length > 5) {
    $("#login_form").submit(function(e) {
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

The form submits fine if I enter the correct values initially. However if "return false" is called only once then it won't submit.

How can I fix this? Calling "return true" doesn't work.

EDIT

My html form:

```html
<form id='login_form' action='login.php' method='post'>
  <div id='form_item'>
    <div id='form_item_left' style='width: 40%; margin-left: -75px; font-size: 18px;'>Username or Email</div>
    <div id='form_item_right'>
      <input id='text' type='text' name='username'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='form_item'>
    <div id='form_item_left' style='font-size: 18px;'>Password</div>
    <div id='form_item_right'>
      <input id='text' type='text' name='password'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='height: 5px;'></div>
  <div id='form_item'>
    <div id='form_item_right'>
      <span style='display: inline-block; width: 60px;'></span>
      <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='remember_me'>
      <span>Remember me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='height: 15px;'></div>
  <div id='form_item' style='text-align: center;'>
    <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the exact purpose of having `stop()` function?

Comment: It stops the form from submitting if the username or password fields are left empty.

Comment: Where are you calling `login()` function?

Comment: When the submit() button is clicked.

Comment: Instead of using the `stop()` function, why not return false?

Comment: That's what the stop() function does.

Comment: In all those if statements in which username and password are not valid there is no need to call stop() function. You don't need stop() function at all. Instead of calling stop() just return false.

Comment: "return false" means "Do nothing at all". So when you return false on submit, it... does nothing at all. This code works fine :)

Comment: Also, in the last if statement you do not need to write return true inside submit() function. Simply, call $("#login_form").submit() if username and password are valid, otherwise don't call $("#login_form").submit at all and just display alert with the message.

Comment: All you need is something like this:
`function login() {
    var username = $("input[name=username]").val();
    var password = $("input[name=password]").val();

    if ( username and password are good) {
        $("#login_form").submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("Username and password are not good.");
    }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, just use `event.preventDefault();` instead of return false.

Your setup using login() and stop() seems overly complex, and you don't seem to be using jQuery submit correctly in this case - the way you are using it, its binding an event handler to the submit event, which is why it stops working - because you bound return false to any submit event from that form.

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (e) {    
    if(condition){
        alert("Error");
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if(condition){
        alert("Error");
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if(condition){
        alert("Success");
        // Do Something
    }
});
```

I think something like this is closer to what you need. If there is an error on submit, preventDefault, if it all checks out, do something without preventDefault.

Again, remember that `$("element").submit(function (e) {` is binding an event handler to the submit event, its not firing a submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found out how to fix it.

The following code worked perfectly.

```js
var eventhandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function login() {
  var username = $("input[name=username]").val();
  var password = $("input[name=password]").val();

  if (username.length < 1) {
    alert("Please enter your username or email address.");
    $("#login_form").bind('submit', eventhandler);
  } else if (username.length > 0 && username.length < 3) {
    alert("Your username or email is incorrect.");
    $("#login_form").bind('submit', eventhandler);
  } else if (password.length < 1) {
    alert("Please enter your password.");
    $("#login_form").bind('submit', eventhandler);
  } else if (password.length > 0 && password.length < 6) {
    alert("Your password is incorrect.");
    $("#login_form").bind('submit', eventhandler);
  }

  if (username.length > 2 && password.length > 5) {
    $("#login_form").unbind('submit', eventhandler);
  }
}
```